# Rails 4 devise - redirect user if not authenticated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

There is *authenticate_user!* in a comments_controller.

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

When a user clicks to create a comment, they are now redirected to users/sign_in page.

But, I want to redirect them to root_url and put a notice to log in. There are login buttons(FB and G+) on home page.

I've looked at [**this**](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated), but when I implement it, I just get a black page with the same URL and *Completed 401 Unauthorized*.

Answer (score 4):

You can add `authenticate_user!` method to the `application_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protected
  def authenticate_user!
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "You must login" unless user_signed_in?
  end
end
```

Comment: I think that this is not the correct definition of authenticate_user! and you will need to pass a aparameter

Answer (score 1):

I added a page to the Devise wiki showing the correct way to do this with a failure app: [Redirect to new registration (sign up) path if unauthenticated](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Redirect-to-new-registration-(sign-up)-path-if-unauthenticated)

The key is to override the `route` method, like so:

```
# app/lib/my_failure_app.rb
class MyFailureApp < Devise::FailureApp
  def route(scope)
    :new_user_registration_url
  end
end
```

and then have Devise use your failure app:

```
# config/initializers/devise.rb
config.warden do |manager|
  manager.failure_app = MyFailureApp
end
```

This approach is preferable to overriding `authenticate_user!` in your controller because it won't clobber a lot of "behind the scenes" stuff Devise does, such as storing the attempted URL so the user can be redirected after successful sign in.

## With multiple user types

If you have `Admin` and `User` Devise resources, you'll probably want to keep the default "new session" functionality for admins. You can do so quite easily by checking what type of scope is being processed:

```
# app/lib/my_failure_app.rb
class MyFailureApp < Devise::FailureApp
  def route(scope)
    scope.to_sym == :user ? :new_user_registration_url : super
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**comments_controller.rb**

```
    before_filter :loged_in?, :only => [:create, :edit, :destroy] #customize to fit your needs

    private

    def loged_in?
      redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Your have to log in' unless current_user
    end
```

it will check if current_user exists, which it will if a user is signed in, otherwise redirects to root path with given notice.