# Edit new user session path when accessing protected page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

When user signs in, user gets redirected to /dashboard/index. So
/dashboard/index is protected with :

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  def index
  end
end
```

Now, if someone tries to access directly /dashboard/index without being logged in. User gets redirected to /users/sign_in with flash message "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."

How can I get the user redirected to root_path (and still get that flash message)?

I have tried unsuccessfully :

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def new_user_session_path(resource)
    root_path
  end
```

Comment: check my answer in here http://stackoverflow.com/a/24232071/1297435

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There Devise wiki has a [recipe/workaround](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated) on how to do this.

It might be easier to just use a custom authenticator though.
Instead of using `before_action :authenticate_user!` that Devise comes with, you can add your own authenticator that redirects somewhere else.

```
class ApplicationController

  protected

  def user_auth
    unless user_signed_in?
      # Set flash message
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end
```

Then tell your controllers to use `user_auth` instead of `authenticate_user!`

Comment: Had to replace def user_auth by def authenticate_user! and it is working greatly! Thank you